# DSC switching back to push

Tags: powershell, dsc

Hi there i got a small problem. I have configured a node to pull the config from my HTTP DSC server. But once it pulls its config the node switched back to push.
My node config looks like this:

```
[DSCLocalConfigurationManager()]
configuration PullClientConfigNames
{
    Node localhost
    {
        Settings
        {
            RefreshMode = 'Pull'
            RefreshFrequencyMins = 30
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $false

        }
        ConfigurationRepositoryWeb DSC-PullSrv
        {
            ServerURL = 'http://DSCPULLSERVER:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc'
            RegistrationKey = 'SomeKey'
            ConfigurationNames = @('ConfigName')
            AllowUnsecureConnection = $true
        }
    }
}
```